# List files with their correct line count [Powershell]

Tags: powershell

I want to generate an excel file that contains some information for files on a directory.
The name, filesize are copied across to the excel spreadsheet correctly, but for the count of lines on each file - the value is 1 for all the files

```
$SourceDir = ".\TestData"


$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File

$Results = foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $FL_Item.Name
        Location = $FL_Item.Directory
        Size_KB = '{0,7:N2}' -f ($FL_Item.Length / 1KB)
        Count = $FL_Item.Count
        }
    }

$Results | Export-Csv -Path "./temp3.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

### Current output

| Name | Size_KB | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test_1 | 45 | 1 |
| Test_2 | 90 | 1 |
| Test_4 | 44 | 1 |
| Test_6 | 120 | 1 |

For Test_1 for instance, there are 50 lines on the file - how can I alter my code
on the powershell script, so that the count is displayed correctly on the excel file?

### Expected

| Name | Size_KB | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test_1 | 45 | 50 |
| Test_2 | 90 | 120 |
| Test_4 | 44 | 43 |
| Test_6 | 120 | 234 |

**Any clue how to populate the line count correctly?**

Comment: You need to read the files with `Get-Content` to be able to count the lines they contain. ;-)

Comment: You need to read thee file contents if you want to get a count of lines, here is one option `Count = ($FL_Item.OpenText().ReadToEnd() -split '\r?\n').Count`

Comment: FYI `$FL_Item.Count` is giving you the count of items in `$FL_Item`; but that variable holds information about the file itself; not the contents of the file - so you're counting how many files are in that variable which points to a signle file.

Comment: Hi Olaf, Thanks for the response. I'll try that

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, will give that a go. Some of the files have large volumes so I guess this will take a while to run through the whole set